# .htaccess and $_GET issue

Tags: .htaccess

My website use an OVH serveur Apache/2.4.38 (Debian10).

I have an issue with my .htaccess file,
(I put it in /var/www/html, see here -> [web tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHdW0.png))

I wanted to add some rewrite rules to have this URL :

https://example.fr/productPage1

instead of :

https://example.fr/productPage.php?id=1

here is what I put on my htaccess :

I tried this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/productPage\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.fr/productPage%1? [R=301,L]
```

But with a 404 error, because the _GET is no longer in the URL,
how can I reach the _GET ?

(I have a lot of php functions using the CRUD method)

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO, kudos for sharing your attempted code. Can you please confirm if you are hitting URL `https://example.fr/productPage.php?id=1` in browser? Which you want to change it to `https://example.fr/productPage1` on browser?

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 yes I can hit the URL `https://example.fr/productPage.php?id=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is: "... the _GET is no longer in the URL, how can I reach the _GET ?"

The answer to that is: you can't, since there is not get argument in that URL. That actually is the whole point of this rewriting: *not* to have an ugly argument in the URL. Instead that argument is part of the *path* component of your desired URL. Which means that is where you need to get it from:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?productPage(\d+)$ /productPage.php?id=$1 [END]
```

You can add an exernal redirection to this internal rewrite if you also want to redirect clients still using the old URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^/?productPage\.php$ /productPage%1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?productPage(\d+)$ /productPage.php?id=$1 [END]
```

You obviously need the rewriting module to be loaded and enabled for this to work.

You should always prefer to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration, *if possible* . In situation where you do not have access to the host configuration you can also use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), but that comes with a number of disadvantages. And you need to enable that feature too (see the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentaiton).

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! `https://example.fr/productPage1` works but I have to change manually the URL. So I think the 301 is not working? I added `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On` on the top of the htaccess file and the `AllowOverride On` in the .conf file

Comment: I checked to be sure but yes, above rules are correct. If things don't work for you then I assume that you either look at results cached from earlier attempts, or that your actual requests look different to what you claim here. Either the path is not actually `/productPakge.php` (maybe an additional prefix?) or you have additional get arguments you never mentioned here.

Comment: I cleaned the cache and checked if my path is the good one (cf the web tree picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHdW0.png). But it's still putting ?id=1

Comment: Then maybe it is your php logic which is responsible for that?

Comment: You will have to start debugging. I cannot do that for you, only you have access to your system. The simply attempt is to start monitoring your clients network traffic: open the browsers development console check in details the responses you get when making the request. If that does not reveal anything unexpected then turn on rewrite logging inside your http server. It allows you to follow what is actually going on inside your rewriting engine on a step by step base. Check the documentation to learn how to do that.